# Three layers transparency

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I have html structure similar to this:

```
<body>
<div class="map"></div>
<div class="map-footer"></div>
</body>
```

[image]

body has a fire image background

.map has a map

.map-footer has an image below map (solid red color, with z-index, covering some .map contents)

If I set .map-footer opacity to 0.5 (for example) it transparents to covered .map area, but what I need is to get it transparent directly to body, with keeping covered .map contents hidden. Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe I have a bad html structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bad structure.  The footer shouldn't be sitting on top of the map at all.  If you *do* want it to sit on top of the map, create two divs: one that sits on top and is opaque and one that sits below and is transparent.

Or just remove the need to sit on top and just make the map shorter (then you don't need to offset the positions of each div).